# CSS/JavaScript/HTML Menu list with nested links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal-8

I have menu list in my page with following structure. When I click any link in the menu the system automatically add class="is-active" to the link. I set *display* of nested links to *none* so they will be visible only by clicking on parent link (see css). However, when I click on one of the child links, the whole submenu of child links disappear. How to achieve that my child links will be visible when I use them? I know I cannot affect parent by child with css, maybe there is some simple javascript workaround.

Thank you in advance!

```css
.menu-item--expanded ul {display: none;}
.menu-item--expanded a.is-active ~ ul {display: block}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<ul>
  <li class="menu-item--expanded">
    <a class="is-active">Link 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link A</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link B</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item--expanded">
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" class="is-active">Link D</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link E</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link F</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're setting is active?

Comment: share the whole code ( including the javascript/jquery )

Comment: you should keep class "is-active" on the first link when you click on child links, share your js to help us understand the full problem

Comment: It is a genereal Drupal 8 menu, I don't know how it assigns the is-active class to links...

Comment: well it seems it's a problem with the script. it shouldn't remove the active class of the parent li when a child li is clicked. Or it should assign a `is-parent-active` class or smth like that. If you can't access the function that gives the active class, then you could something like suggested in the answer below. If that doesn't work let me know and i'll make an example for you

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this on javascript:

```
$('li').on('click', function(evt){
    $(evt.target).parent().css('display', 'none');
})
```

so when a list item is clicked then set as display:none the parent element, so ul. Maybe have a check around the setting of css to check is-active class too, like:

```
if($(evt.target).hasClass('is-active')){
 //switch to display none
}
```

Comment: You meant `$(evt.target).parent().css…` don't you ?

Comment: Yes, I realised it after I posted it but fixed it, thanks for pointing it too.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using jquery for this.
The following code will change the display from the child ul when clicked on a parent.

make sure that the child lists are display: none with css.

```
.menu-item--expanded > ul{
display: none;
}

$('.menu-item--expanded').click(function () {
  $(this).find($('ul')).css({
    'display' : 'block'
  });
});
```

to make sure that only the childs of the parent page where you are are visible use the following code:

note: the else clause is not needed actually since your css will already set display none on those items. but i mentioned it just to make it clear.

```
$('.menu-item--expanded').each(function () {
  if($(this).find($('>a')).hasClass('is-active')){
    $(this).find($('ul')).css({
      'display' : 'block'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).find($('ul')).css({
      'display' : 'none'
    });
  }
});
```

hope this helps.